# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] Invalid XML with Magento API

Tags: magento

"Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] Invalid XML" outputs when I try to import bulk products into Magento. 
I have a excel file, a product per line, I have about 178 products. Everything is ok until it goes to the 22 line. The Fatal Error outputs.

Anyone knows what's happened. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have used some special characters (like "`<`" (left chevron) or "`>`" (right chevron) or "`'`" (single quote)), in the product existing in line #22.

You need to make sure that the special characters are converted / used by the corresponding [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) only in such scenarios, directly in the excel file only.

If you don't convert / delete those special characters in the excel file only, then in the API they get used up as the characters to be used for the API. This is a ***little bit similar*** to the way how SQL Injection occurs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But I think it's still not working. I am really tortured by this fatal errors. Even I filter any kind of characters with PHP(and I var_dump() it before I call the api, it's so safety data to database), it still throw this exception! But when I delete the suspect character directly in the excel, everything is OK!

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964921/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-103-attribute-include-in-menu-is-r