# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [103] Attribute "include_in_menu" is required

Tags: magento

"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [103] Attribute "include_in_menu" is required." was throwed when I using Magento API to create a category.

In the Magento API, it says I need an array like this,

```
         array(
            'name'=>'Newopenerp',
            'is_active'=>1,
            'include_in_menu'=>2,
            'available_sort_by'=>'position',
            'default_sort_by'=>'position'
           )
```

When I run my script in localhost with Magento 1.5.1, everything looks fine. While in the server with Magento 1.5.0, this exception was thrown. I am wondering if this is caused by version change.

I tried my best to debug this, got nothing after one day. I make sure this is a problem of Magento API, maybe there is a another data type for '`include_in_menu`' in Magento 1.5.0.

I really want to know what happened here!

**PS:**
I got some useful information at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtlmage/forums/forum/1009350/topic/4028894. But it's not in English so I can't get what it means. Hope it's helpful for anyone's help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to this path "`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/`", and open this file "`wsdl.xml`". Then go to this line #187, and you will find this following code block for the Magento v1.5.0.1:-

```
<complexType name="catalogCategoryEntityCreate">
    <all>
        <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="position" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="available_sort_by" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="custom_design" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="custom_design_apply" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="custom_design_from" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="custom_design_to" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="custom_layout_update" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="default_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="display_mode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="is_anchor" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="landing_page" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="meta_description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="meta_keywords" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="meta_title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="page_layout" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <element name="url_key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </all>
</complexType>
```

Here if you follow all the elements, you will be able to know what all attributes / elements are required.

As for your question, you are right that in Magento v1.5.1.0, the element "`include_in_menu`" is present for the same attribute. However, the Magento v1.5.0.1 doesn't have any such element present in the "`wsdl.xml`" file, and you will require to remove this element from your array elements list.

Also I would like to let you know that I would not recommend you to add this element in the "`complexType`" data, since that will mean that you are making holes in the core & that will only hamper your Magento when you will make any upgradation of your Magento core.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness help. I finally know where to find the API attributes. But it still throws the exception even I delete the include_in_menu from the array in Magento V1.5.0.1. Then I check the wsdl.xml in above path in our server file, there is no this attribute just like the code paste above. I have no idea what's going on, maybe I should try Magento v1.5.1 in the server.

Comment: If it's possible for you to upgrade your Magento to the latest version 1.5.1.0, then please proceed with it. It's always best to be in the latest league.

Comment: Yes. We have upgrade Magento to 1.5.1.0 on the server. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another question to consult you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023834/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-schema-can I think I need to make some tuition then LOL

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `include_in_menu` be a boolean, therefore `1` or `0`?

Comment: Well, I paste this piece of code from Magento API. I have 1 for include_in_menu in my code, but it still not working. It throws this exception no matter what you assign it. So I am wondering if this data type is different in Magento 1.5.0.