# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'

Tags: magento, soap, wsdl

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
```

First, I am sorry to say I put these question here cause so many same question in stackoverflow. But it seems not any fit for me.

I use Magento SOAP2 API for times, this error not happed often. But it keeps make a fatal error when I run my script today.

I have looked up for some method to solve this problem, for example, some articles told me to change this code in /app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc/wsdl.xml

```
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemalocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
</import>
```

to this

```
<!-- 
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
-->
```

I followed this, but it make another error like below,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected <import> in schema
```

Then I have no idea what's wrong, cause this script is always running perfectly but today and I even do not change any line of the code. My question is,
1, Any method to solve it?
2, Can I make this xmlsoap.org xml file to localhost or my own server so that my script will not depend on a file out my server.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please never tamper with the default elements of any Magento API V2 WSDL Configuration file. It's a basic rule.

Please keep in mind to write these following elements at the beginning of each custom WSDL file or make sure that these following elements are present at the beginning of the WSDL file of your target existing module:-

1. "`definition`" element (`<definitions>` - start tag)
2. "`types`" element (`<types>` - start tag)
3. "`schema`" element (`<schema>` - start tag)
4. "`import`" element (`<import />` - singleton tag, with no end tag)

Then you can continue with defining the Complex Data Types of the Magento API V2 for that Custom Module.

You can very well get the concept of all these by looking into some of the existing Magento API V2 WSDL files.

---

Now coming back to your questions...

**1. Any method to solve it?**
As I said before, please maintain the above-mentioned elements definitions at the beginning of your WSDL file.

The "`import`" statement should have been:-
`<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />`
with no end tag.
Also the attribute name is "`schemaLocation`" & not "`schemalocation`". Follow the Camel Casing please.

---

**2. Can I make this xmlsoap.org xml file to localhost or my own server so that my script will not depend on a file out my server?**

Yes you can, but you need to know & maintain two vital points:-

1. Both of the attributes "`namespace`" & "`schemaLocation`" must be of type URI, according to the W3C specifications. So your local files for both of these attributes must also be accessible in your local browser, using HTTP protocol.
2. If you are maintaining it in your local hard disk, then you are forgetting about one golden rule of upgradation, for Schema of the SOAP/1.1 encoding file. This is because if (only if) W3C upgrades this file in this same URI, then your Magento will be able to take it automatically if the general URI is provided; otherwise you will need to download that upgraded file again to your server.

Other than these two major points, everything is okay & you are good to go.

---

Nevertheless, I hope that I have answered all your queries. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like,

//create soap object

```
`$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');`
```

// create authorized session id using api user name and api key

```
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$productinfo = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.info',16);
echo "<pre>";print_r($productinfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just some details for accepted solution.**

1. Enter the address of the schema location in your browser:

   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
2. Save the XML result in the browser in a file called `encoding.xsd` (save file as).
3. Copy this file to your magento web root directory e.g. `/var/www/magento/`
4. Search for all schemaLocation entries in wsd*.xml files from magento root folder with e.g. 
   `find . -name "wsdl*.xml" | xargs grep schemaLocation 2>/dev/null | grep org`

   On my system 12 matching files in ./app/code/core and 2 matching files from 3rd party extensions in ./app/code/local.
5. Change the line in **every** matching xml file
   `<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   schemalocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">`

   to
   `<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="../../../../encoding.xsd">`

   **Remark**: In this case the encoding.xsd file is 4 directories higher relativ to the api path of `http://sampleshop.com/testsystem/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl` 
   In your live system 2 (without index.php) or 3 (with index.php) times `"../"` could be correct.
6. Try the SOAP calls from local and remote server
   **Example Script** 
   `<?php
   $proxy = new SoapClient('http://sampleshop.com/testsystem/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
   $sessionId = $proxy->login('MagentoSoapUser', 'SoapApiKey');
   $result = $proxy->directoryCountryList($sessionId);
   var_dump($result);
   ?>`

   This solutions worked for me, just wanted to add some details as it takes me some time to get it running.
   **System: magento CE 1.7.0.2** 
   **SOAP: php-soap** with php version 5.3 on magento server and 5.6 on remote server.

Kozure