# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from …

Tags: magento, soap, ubuntu

I'm getting the error,

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'

1. SOAP and xml-rpc modules are intstalled.
2. I have followed [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023834/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-schema-ca) and verified the WSDL.
3. I have commented

   `<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />`  in /app/code/core/Mage/Api/etc/wsdl.xml.

Any other steps to be followed? Should I update php, php-soap? It's working fine with Windows.

Comment: Is there nobody to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to successfully run the soap, you require 
php-soap, xml rpc and openssl.

It works now with commenting in `entire project` (all xml files)

```
//<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />  in entire magento project
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the schemas.xmlsoap.org is reachable from your Server
Try it with:

```
wget http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
```

if you get an error like "host not found" check your dns!

Comment: This URL was unavailable today from different locations. Probably Akamai (their CDN) has some issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting following errors on my localhost wamp server

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/


Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
```

I had not enabled  open ssl and xml rpc as mentioned by **Angelin Nadar**. Once I enabled this the problem solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use 
SOAP_1_1
In your soap client.