# Parsing Schema: can't import schema - new server

Tags: php, xml, soap, xsd, soap-client

I had a schema hosted on some server and all my PHP and .Net apps connected to it with no issues.

After moving the schema to a new location, .Net apps can still connect and parse correctly, but all PHP apps give the following error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from "schema location url"

I can open the URL in the browser, and as said, .Net apps work fine.

What is causing this?

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003549/soap-error-parsing-schema-cant-import-schema-from

Comment: @Soliyappan Thanks for the tips, but there has been no change on schema file, only the location that has been changed