# Magento in intranet cannot import WSDL schema

Tags: magento, soap, proxy, wsdl, xampp

I have the Magento 1.7.0.2 CE instance installed on the local machine (intranet) using XAMPP and Windows Server 2012. I need to call its SOAP v2 API (WS-I Compliance = no, and it cannot be changed) from the other machine within the intranet.

When I try to call the SOAP "login" function I get following error:

```
“SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can’t import schema from ‘http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/’“
```

Important may be that the host where Magento is installed **HAS NOT GOT DNS NAME** so it base_url is set to the machine's public ip, visible from the intranet.

Here is what I tried:

1. As the magento host is in the intranet I have configured the proxy on XAMPP for outside calls so the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ is accessible. Nothing has changed.
2. I tried to remove the import clause from app\code\core\Mage\Api\etc\wsdl2.xml and wsdl.xml that I have found but then I recieve another error:

   ```
   "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected import in schema"
   ```
3. I have seen:
   [Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023834/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-schema-ca)

## I have found a workaround:

This is ugly but works. In the standard way wsdl file is taken using full path e.g.:
    _http://[host]/index.php/api /v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1

1. I have reviewed each directory in
   /app/code/core/Mage/*/etc/wsdl.xml and removed the import clause from it.
2. Clear magento cache (var/cache).
3. I have downloaded the result wsdl using browser.
4. Then removed each import statement
5. Then saved it in the root of magento. (I am not sure if this is the case because I have further removed it and whole thing still seemed to work.)
6. Clear magento cache

Comment: Are you able to view wsdl file in browser ?

Comment: Yes, from the host machine and from the intranet also.
Calling:
http://[intranetip]/mage1/api/v2_soap?wsdl

Comment: Then it must be some field/element placed wrongly in wsdl file. Can you send me your wsdl xml file.

Comment: It was not customized. This is standard magento v2 wsdl:
http://pastebin.com/dTQugaHf

Comment: have you disabled the cache ? and wsdl cache ?

Comment: I have disabled it in the Magento backend and cleared in /var/cache

Comment: Check your settings System Operations > Web Services > Magento Core API Settings.

But I strongly suspect that your wsdl.xml is not valid.

Comment: But how it can be invalid if it was not changed anyway? The shop is a fresh installation. Without any customizations.

Comment: can you add here your wsdl file ?